# Is there a way to JUST cover the page with background video in CSS?

Tags: css, video, background, size

(I'm just learning CSS, so please don't yell at me >.> ... )
I have a rather big HD video that I wanted to put in the background.
The way I had it set up at first was

```
#video-background {      
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      z-index: -1000;
      background-size: cover;}
```

html:

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay loop="loop" id="video-background" muted="muted">
  <source src="bg3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <script>
  document.getElementById('video-background').playbackRate=0.4;
  </script>
</video>
```

I tried various methods to bring it down, like change `background-size` to `contain`, adding `object-fit: cover`, some other solutions I found on SO ...
Then I changed `min` to `max` for width and height (i dunno why i didn't do that in the first place, it totally makes sense...)

So now the video does fit within the screen, but because of aspect ratio, I have empty space on the side.

Is there any way to fit the video so that it matches either height or width of the screen, and then goes off screen however much it needs to to maintain its aspect ratio? In other words, how do I minimize the size of the video while still having it cover the whole screen (even if some parts get cut off)?

I've decided that for now, the easiest way is to just set `max-width` to 100% :| and remove any reference to height ... but I'm not sure if the ratio of width to height for any standard resolution is greater than that of the video. But this should work as long as that's true.

Edit: I can see that my temp solution isn't that great for when you scale the page itself %\ ... like if you're doing a split screen. Then the video stays at full width, but now there are gaps on top and bottom >.< ..... *gruuuuunt*

Comment: Can you include a sample of the HTML?

Comment: have you tried `background-size: 100% auto;` ?

Comment: @Taki, yeah, that doesn't work :<

Comment: Your setup works fine here, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BxpZRZ?editors=1000 do you have some working demo?

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal, it cuts off on my screen: https://imgur.com/a/xJMJmtm

Comment: browser details?

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal Chrome. For some reason it doesn't even run in IE %\ ... says something about blocked content ...